# Jboss 6 - Deployment failed for CDI enabled bean

Tags: cdi, jboss6.x

Created a sample project with CDI as in site [CDI Sample](http://java.dzone.com/articles/java-ee6-events-lightweight), but while try to deploy it in Jboss 6, getting below error.Is there any other lib file need to be include to resolve this issue?

```
 Lib jars:
 javaee-api-7.0.jar
 javax.inject-1.jar
```

`Deployment Error:
2015-02-12 12:25:21,852 INFO  [org.jboss.ejb3.deployers.JBossASKernel] (WorkerThread#0[192.168.10.119:61928])   and supplies:
2015-02-12 12:25:21,852 INFO  [org.jboss.ejb3.deployers.JBossASKernel] (WorkerThread#0[192.168.10.119:61928])   jndi:HelloObserver
2015-02-12 12:25:21,852 INFO  [org.jboss.ejb3.deployers.JBossASKernel] (WorkerThread#0[192.168.10.119:61928]) Added bean(jboss.j2ee:ear=J2eeObserver.ear,jar=J2eeObserver-ejb.jar,name=HelloObserver,service=EJB3) to KernelDeployment of: J2eeObserver-ejb.jar
2015-02-12 12:25:22,048 ERROR [org.jboss.kernel.plugins.dependency.AbstractKernelController] (WorkerThread#0[192.168.10.119:61928]) Error installing to Create: name=vfs:///E:/jboss-6.1.0.Final/server/default/deploy/J2eeObserver.ear_WeldBootstrapBean state=Configured: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.jboss.weld.util.ApiAbstraction.annotationTypeForName(ApiAbstraction.java:86) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.weld.ejb.EJBApiAbstraction.<init>(EJBApiAbstraction.java:36) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.BeanDeployment.<init>(BeanDeployment.java:100) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.WeldBootstrap$DeploymentVisitor.visit(WeldBootstrap.java:185) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.WeldBootstrap$DeploymentVisitor.visit(WeldBootstrap.java:197) [:6.1.0.Final]
    ......`

`2015-02-12 12:25:22,074 WARN  [org.jboss.profileservice.management.upload.remoting.DeployHandler] (WorkerThread#0[192.168.10.119:61928]) Failed to complete command: [start] for deployment: names=[J2eeObserver.ear]: org.jboss.deployers.client.spi.IncompleteDeploymentException: Summary of incomplete deployments (SEE PREVIOUS ERRORS FOR DETAILS):`

`DEPLOYMENTS MISSING DEPENDENCIES:
  Deployment "jboss-injector:topLevelUnit=J2eeObserver.ear,unit=J2eeObserver-ejb.jar,bean=HelloObserver,interceptor=org.jboss.weld.integration.ejb.SessionBeanInterceptor" is missing the following dependencies:
    Dependency "<UNKNOWN jboss-injector:topLevelUnit=J2eeObserver.ear,unit=J2eeObserver-ejb.jar,bean=HelloObserver,interceptor=org.jboss.weld.integration.ejb.SessionBeanInterceptor>" (should be in state "Installed", but is actually in state "** UNRESOLVED Demands 'jboss-switchboard:appName=J2eeObserver,module=J2eeObserver-ejb,name=HelloObserver' **")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem resolved, when start the Jboss AS 6 with paramter 
`run -Dcom.sun.jersey.server.impl.cdi.lookupExtensionInBeanManager=true`

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you're using JBoss EAP 6 not JBoss AS 6 (the community version corresponding to EAP 6 is JBoss AS 7.1.1). So you're programming model is Java EE 6 not 7.
So you should use `java-ee-6.jar` to compile but not include it to your deployment: the server provides it. You don't need inject lib.

Comment: am using Jboss AS 6. Even tried with javaee-api-6.0.jar but still getting same exception. App is deploying if i removed the bean.xml file from the ear, but the App is not working. Note: Same ear is works fine in wildfly 8

Comment: As I said. Don't use AS 6. It was abandoned in favor of AS 7 and thus is totally buggy and have no community. So try with AS 7.1.1 or EAP 6.3